# Spring MVC jar load in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have two classes and an interface with the same package and name like ,

com.myapp.A in different jars (Say X,Y,Z). Is there any way to mention that the spring mvc application should not take the interface A but should take only the class A from this specific X jar.

Comment: If you need both, they must be loaded in different `ClassLoader`s.

Comment: It's not that I need both.. I need to exclude the interface A while loading.. any possibility to do that.. for example, I need a scenario where I want all classes with name "A" to be loaded but no interface named "A" should be loaded..